# Overwrite file overwriting file version

Tags: development, csom

Is it possible to overwrite file in document libraries with versioning enabled?

I am unable to find any information about this.

Comment: Question is not clear. Is it about OOB interface or custom code?

Comment: @AlokKumarGupta custom c# code using Microsoft.SharePoint2013.CSOM ver 15

Comment: What is an "overwrite" in this i.e. what do you think will happen - all previous versions of file will be removed or the currently uploaded file will become latest version?

Comment: @AlokKumarGupta currently uploaded file will have same version number which was the latest before upload, overwriting file behind it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To overwrite file version you should use `SystemUpdate` method. For a long time is was available only in [Server Side Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.systemupdate.aspx).

According to [Office Dev blog post](https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-august-2016-updated) it is now available in CSOM also but only in SharePoint Online/Office 365 environment, as mentioned in [this post](http://microsofttouch.fr/english/b/vince365/posts/systemupdate-method-available-in-csom-at-last).

Here is CSOM [SystemUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.systemupdate.aspx) method description in MSDN.